# Entity Framework Configuration Seed method not calling SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I've overridden SaveChanges method of my CustomDbContext:DbContext, to search for specific interface in entity which defines a particular property. If interface is present, a property defined by that interface should be set to a default value if it is null, and that is only when adding a new entity.

What I've noticed though is that when I'm using Code First with migrations, Seed method of Configuration:DbMigrationsConfiguration class is not invoking my overridden SaveChanges, so when it's trying to save seeds, exception is thrown because that required property is not set.

Is there a documented explanation why Seed is not using SaveChanges of your custom DbContext?

Comment: I can't answer the question, but I think you can safely call `myContext.SaveChanges()` manually at the end of `Seed`. The second call of the base `SaveChanges` that EF does internally then does nothing because everything is in state `Unchanged` after your manual call. You probably know that... but just in case you don't :)

Comment: That is how I'm doing it now :) I've moved seeders to separate static classes that do the seeding / invoke SaveChanges each on its own, but I was wondering why Entity Framework is not using SaveChanges from CustomDbContext giving that Configuration class is aware of the type :)